How do I use XLOOKUP
I am trying to use XLOOKUP but not sure what I need to put in the last two prompts (have read that they are not a necessity so what shall I populate with a 0?)

Try reading the MSFT Documentations here which might help. also you have posted 3 questions earlier, not replied to anyone of them, how would users know whether any one of the solutions suggestions posted would helped you or not. Please try to reply members as well!

There's two options: don't use them at all (you can stop putting arguments after your return array), or leave them empty, unless you need one: =XLOOKUP(A1 , B1:B10 , C1:C10 , , , -1) will search for the value in A1, within area B1:B10 and return a corresponding value from C1:C10, looking bottom to top (instead of top to bottom), but the not found and match mode are left blank. But yeah, read the MSFT Mayukh has linked to.

You could try using VLOOKUP ... XLOOKUP is supposed to be an improvement but it seems to have become more complicated!

I needed to go to the left instead of the right like vlookup.  The above comments worked successfully.
